# Cartthrob Stripe Gateway Blank Screen after checkout

Tags: cartthrob, error, checkout, stripe, blank-screen

I have a weird issue with Stripe and Cartthrob.

Version Info.
EE- 2.5.5
Cartthrob - 2.4

When submitting the checkout form using the stripe gateway. In firefox and safari (some customers have reported chrome as well but it works on my machine) the order gets processed correctly and payment shows up at stripe but the return parameter never runs.

To clarify whats happening the group/template from which the checkout is happening is store/checkout.  Once the checkout is complete the return is supposed to take you to store/thanks.

Instead the the site stays (or reloads not sure) store/checkout but the page is blank.

Customers obviously think there is an error and click the back button.  The cart is not cleared and we have instances where customers have submitted the same order and got a token reference error.

Once again the payment is reaching stripe its just how the order confirmation return is not working that is causing the problems.

I am aware that stripe uses it's own javascript that it embeds into the page.

I have removed all my external javascript from the page. I also made sure the checkout form does not have a custom id and that the required fields do not have  a name value associated with them as per the payment documentation inside the plugin.

My console is showing no javascript errors and all the stripe js files are linking correctly from the source code from what I see.

Please help guys I haven't seen the issue anywhere else and I'm out of ideas.

Thanks for the great plugin.

Ben

Comment: Hi Ben, Have you followed the instructions on the Cartthrob Payments settings area for stripe? Is your php over or equal to version 5.3, have you checked your php error logs as php errors can lead to blank screens? Thanks!

Comment: John, Sorry for the slow replay I didn't get a notification on your response.  I'm running php 5.4.22, and have followed the settings for Stripe.  Its not on an SSL but its not required for test mode. All other settings are solid.  I haven't seen any PHP errors related and it works in some browsers and not others which is confusing.

Comment: New development found.  It will process correctly if you are logged in to the admin section but if you are logged out you get the blank screen.

Comment: "Logged out member id" has also been set to anon and "user not required to be logged in" is set to no

Answer (score -1):

This was caused by a conflict between Cart Throb and the Zenbu plugin.  Zenbu was not a "have to have" on the site so after its removal its back to working correctly.

Comment: Ben - can you elaborate on the conflict so others can benefit form it?

Comment: I don't have much more to elaborate on. Zenbu was used to view more channel entriy detail from the control panel, and when non logged-in members checkout they received a blank page.  It could have been a variety of issues.

1. Non logged in members might have needed access to the  plugin from their member group.

2. Conflict between Cart Throb and Zenbu when creating a new order entry.

Or anything else.  I didn't truly debug it I just removed Zenbu since it was not necessary for the sites functionality.